# Python Pandas - Repeat dict to fit in MultiIndex Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, multi-index

I have the structure of a MultiIndex Dataframe that I want to use (inspired from [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers)). I want to instantiate it at each level with a dict.

MultiIndex Dataframe general structure:

```
import pandas as pd

def mklbl(prefix, n):
    return ["%s%s" % (prefix, i) for i in range(n)]

miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [mklbl("X", 2), mklbl("Y", 2), mklbl("Z", 2)]
)

columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']

dfmi = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        # Code below from the documentation. To replace??
        # np.arange(len(miindex) * len(columns)).reshape(
        #   (len(miindex), len(columns))
        ),
        index=miindex,
        columns=columns,
    )
    .sort_index()
    .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

I would like that to replace somehow the above commented code by several repetitions of the following dictionary, which fit with the MultiIndex,

```
my_dict = {'A': [False, False, True, True], 
           'B': [False, True, False, True], 
           'C': [0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

such that I have as a final result:

```
               A       B   C
X0 Y0 Z0   False   False   0
           False   True    0
           True    False   0
           True    True    0
      Z1   False   False   0
           False   True    0
           True    False   0
           True    True    0
   Y1 Z0   False   False   0
           False   True    0
           True    False   0
           True    True    0
      Z1   False   False   0
           False   True    0
           True    False   0
           True    True    0
X1 Y0 Z0   False   False   0
           False   True    0
           True    False   0
           True    True    0
      Z1   False   False   0
           False   True    0
           True    False   0
           True    True    0
   Y1 Z0   False   False   0
           False   True    0
           True    False   0
           True    True    0
      Z1   False   False   0
           False   True    0
           True    False   0
           True    True    0
```

I tried to play around with `pd.concat()` without success. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

prod = product(mklbl("X", 2), mklbl("Y", 2), mklbl("Z", 2))

tmp = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

out = pd.concat({p: tmp for p in prod})
```

Alternatively, if you already have `dfmi`, use a cross-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = (dfmi[[]]
 .reset_index()
 .merge(pd.DataFrame(my_dict), how='cross')
)

out = (out
 .set_index(list(out)[:dfmi.index.nlevels])
 .rename_axis(index=[None]*dfmi.index.nlevels)
)
```

Output:

```
                A      B  C
X0 Y0 Z0 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
      Z1 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
   Y1 Z0 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
      Z1 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
X1 Y0 Z0 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
      Z1 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
   Y1 Z0 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
      Z1 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to fill your dataframe with the dict you should add one more level with the length of you dataframe columns:

```
miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [mklbl("X", 2), mklbl("Y", 2), mklbl("Z", 2), mklbl("", 4)]
)
```

Then you can add your dict by looping over the index like this:

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame(index=miindex, columns=columns)
for index_x, data_x in data_df.groupby(level=0, ):
    for index_y, data_y in data_x.loc[index_x].groupby(level=0):
        for index_z, data_z in data_y.loc[index_y].groupby(level=0):
            for col_name, col_values in imy_dict.items():
                data_df.loc[(index_x, index_y, index_z), col_name] = col_values
```

The results looks like:

```
print(data_df)

                A      B  C
X0 Y0 Z0 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
      Z1 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
   Y1 Z0 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
      Z1 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
X1 Y0 Z0 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
      Z1 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
   Y1 Z0 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
      Z1 0  False  False  0
         1  False   True  0
         2   True  False  0
         3   True   True  0
```